# changing t4 template will not remove build error

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, t4

I have a t4 template that transforms correctly, the cs file has no build errors. the error window continues to report the error as if the template was not changed.

Comment: I ended up pushing my changes and dumping all my local copies of code. i recloned the repo and now it builds, there was some t4 relic that was interfering with the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up running a `git clean -fdx` to remove any build artifacts. I also don't track the cs files that the templates create. after saving the t4 templates i was able to rebuild